# The origin of fermions if there is no SUSY

Tags: supersymmetry, fermions

From the pure mathematical viewpoint, how could we explain the emergence of fermion fields if we managed to probe that SUSY is non-existent in the real world at any energy (of course, this is unfeasible in our timelife, likely). Reciprocally, given the facts that fermions do exist, is that a proof that some kind of SUSY should exist at a high enough energy?

Comment: Do you want to allow particles to have half-integer spin (which is a valid projective representation of the rotation group)? Then you probably want to use fermion fields. SUSY need not have anything to do with it.

Comment: Right, but wherever you have a fermion field AND a bosonic field, you can build up certain supersymmetry transformation. Of course, and I speak from the viewpoint of a stringer fan (not a devoted fan, but a fan), the match of certain fermionic field to a given bosonic field is hard. Indeed, we do know that, excepting bootstrap models, known particles are not supersymmetric partnerts to each other, not at least as the MSSM requires, that is why we search for superpartners, with no fortune yet...

Comment: It would be real nice if the orbits in our solar system were perfect circles instead of ellipses too

Answer (score 1):

Probably, you have asked the question from the opposite direction. Because fermion fields are more **natural** than scalar fields.

Bosonic spin-$0$ fields have the problem of **naturalness** which is actually the reason behind the hierarchy problem (by the way naturalness is a definite term, not to be confused by the every-day usage, that I am going to define below). As a matter of fact, supersymmetry has the goal, coming from the very roots of the idea, to solve the hierarchy problem by making the scalar fields natural. I will come back to SUSY after I give some details about the matter.

The **naturalness principle** is defined as the following.

> A parameter of a theory can be much smaller than unity only if it increases the symmetry by setting it to zero.

It means that the smallness or vanishing of a parameter is protected by a symmetry. Otherwise, in the natural case, that parameter would be unit.

For example, a spin-1/2 particle can have arbitrarily small mass, like neutrinos, because setting it to zero implies chiral symmetry. A gauge boson can have a zero mass, like photons, because it becomes gauge invariant. However a scalar boson having a small mass, i.e. $\sim 10^2$ GeV, is not natural since setting it to zero would not increase the symmetry.

Indeed, Higgs squared-mass, a parameter of the Higgs potential, is very small according to the natural units of physics:
$$
\frac{G_F}{G_N} \sim \frac{m_H^2}{M_{Pl}^2} \sim 10^{-34}
$$
where $G_F\equiv 2\lambda / m^2_H$ is the Fermi coupling constant (or weak scale), $G_N \equiv 1/8\pi M_{Pl}^2$ is the Newton's gravitational constant, and $M_{Pl}$ is the reduced Planck mass.

As you may see, the problem is why the Higgs scale is so small. If you calculate the quantum corrections to this parameter, i.e. for one-loop,
$$
\tag{1}
\Delta m_H^2 = \frac{3}{8 \pi^2} (g_B - |\lambda_F|^2) \Lambda_{UV}^2 + \ldots
$$
where $g_B$ is the coupling constant of a boson, $\lambda_F$ is the coupling constant of a fermion in the theory, and $\lambda_{UV}$ is the cut-off scale of the theory. So, for a cut-off scale of 550 GeV, the Higgs mass would make the theory dangerously unstable, especially for weak bosons. The mass of the Higgs is likely to blow up to the Planck scale.

It is very much similar to a thermodynamic situation for some large number of particles at a temperature T, and a particle at rest inserted to this thermal bath. According to the statistical mechanics, the gas of particles at temperature T would rapidly bring the particle at rest to thermal equilibrium by collisions of the gas particles, very much analogous to the quantum fluctuations that can be as high as $\Lambda_{UV}$ in the vacuum interacting with the Higgs field at small scale. If the cut-off scale is free to go up to the Planck scale, then the Higgs mass would get corrections at the same scale, as well. This completely unnatural in this sense.

More interestingly, this unnaturalness of the Higgs boson is due its **spinless nature**. There is no symmetry in the Standard Model that can allow the squared-mass parameter of the Higgs field to be so small, except if we assume a very precise cancellation for the quantum corrections from different particles of different energies. This cancellation precision is in the order of magnitude of 1 part in $10^{34}$, as classical example, like a pencil balancing on a table that has a tip of 1mm wide but a length as long as the solar system!

So, if you assume there is supersymmetry in nature, it sets all the parameters of a scalar to the parameters of a fermion which allows the scalar fields to have as arbitrary small masses as fermions by putting each boson-fermion pair in a doublet that has exactly the same parameters in orther to cancel the quadratic terms in Eq.(1). Indeed, setting the parameters to zero would increase the symmetry, i.e., supersymmetry. Thus, the scalar fields are natural in SUSY models.

Therefore, your question should ask the opposite, **what is the origin of scalars if there is no SUSY?** The answer is, of course, "nobody knows". However, there are some proposals like **Technicolor model** which assumes Higgs is a composite particle like neutral pion by introducing a copy of quarks as techni-quarks, and **preonic models** which introduces sub-particles to almost all SM particles including Higgs. These models solve the naturalness problem by break down the scalars at some cut-off scale, similar to pions which are also scalars but composed of quarks, and are natural because at energies higher than 250 MeV they will tear apart into their quarks.

Comment: Aren't massless bosons natural due to conformal symmetry ? Because Lagrangian with massless bosons would give rise to a ?CFT

Comment: In the case of a classical theory, you would be right: $m=0$ for scalar field would increase the symmetry by giving rise to conformal symmetry. However, this is not the case for quantum field theories, since the radiative correction, $\Delta m^2_H$, I mentioned above is nonzero (worse: quadratic), even if $m \rightarrow 0$. So, a quantum field theory with a massless scalar is still unnatural.